# How to get multiple-steps ahead forecast with STL model in fable-r?

Tags: r, forecasting, fable-r

### My purpose is forecast multiple-step without re-estimation. And I will update new observation to next forecast.

I did not using `fit` and apply `forecast(h=7)` because this function using `fitted value` to forecast next observation.

##### I used following codes to get 1-step ahead forecast with `stretch_tsibble` to do it.

```r
library(fable)
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
us_accidental_deaths <- as_tsibble(USAccDeaths)

stretch_dt <- us_accidental_deaths %>%
  stretch_tsibble(.init = 60, .step = 1)

fit_train <- stretch_dt %>%
  # keep same estimate period with each .id
  filter_index(. ~ '1977 Dec') %>%
  model(stl_ets_mod = decomposition_model(
    STL(value, ~ season(window = 12)),
    ETS(season_adjust ~ season("N")),
    SNAIVE(season_year)
  ),
  arima_mod = ARIMA(value))
```

##### It's ok when I refit `ARIMA` model

```r
fit_train %>% 
  select(arima_mod) %>% 
  refit(stretch_dt) %>% 
  forecast(h = 1)
```

##### But I met error when I refit `STL` model.

```r
fit_train %>% 
  select(stl_ets_mod) %>% 
  refit(stretch_dt) %>% 
  forecast(h = 1)
```

Many thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is

```
! no applicable method for 'refit' applied to an object of class "c('decomposition_model', 'model_combination')"
```

`refit()` is not available for all models.

It is not clear how a refit should work for an STL decomposition. The STL components are specific to the data set used for training. If the model is applied to a different data set, potentially of a different length, what should the components be?